# How to change the typescript type of object within array on inherited class?

Tags: typescript

[Link to code on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-dev.20220215#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwge2dqCA3gFAJlLYB2kUArvPggBQCURAvsZ8SmhgEoBTACYJBADwiDKwjDjwES5CtWj0IjVkVLLyYWgAdBUVjrLdlw7ILAA5bBADq%20ANZaluslEERaUSghqgmYInNygNHCIvOhYVBDAAJaUxtrKEdBRCABuwMi0ggBcRAgA2snCEsWUtAC2IMYAusXyjJzKsFQ06ppshO3kufk2zH0hyt6%20-ggA8iAAVoLwAHRDBWBMEAAWiWCreQUsIWHEPKixAELY4mKS0rJxlAnJqR5ka0Ul5TJVCDX1TWKQlEAzInVUdAYBHc4z0hmMpk8ZG2u32wwQAF4yo1jlxTuDIAgAO55ZCYv6CIkIK7iUzEEnIZBo9asZYAM3wAFE4FsmExclBEiBkII5ot4ECRGwMQA%20NKDYCC4WihZLCDLKw2exOVymdgsIA)

I want to be able to store type-safe instances of "Red" inside the "Box." Switching `abstract value: { [index: number]: Color }` to `abstract value: { [index: number]: Any }` prevents the error bellow, however it is not type-safe.

```
abstract class Color {
    constructor () {}
}

class Red extends Color {
    constructor () {
        super()
    }

    doesNotWork() {
        return true
    }
}

abstract class Container {
    abstract value: { [index: number]: Color }
    constructor () {}
    values () {
        return Object.values(this.value)
    }
}

class Box extends Container {
    value: { [index: number]: Red }
    constructor () {
        super()
        this.value = []
    }
}

const wall = new Box()

wall.values().forEach((varibleObject: Red) => {
    varibleObject.doesNotWork()
})
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqEVJm) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: How about having a `Generic Container` as in `abstract class Container<TColor extends Color> `? Is there any constraint to having it this way?

Comment: @NalinRanjan Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for. I had no idea you could pass type parameters this way. I especially appreciate the inclusion of the "extends" feature, that extra step is awesome to have.

Comment: @jcalz This approach could work, but I think it's significantly messier than using generics on class definition.